# How to temporarily mount a hard drive partition as read-only using Nautilus?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, nautilus, mount, hibernate

I hibernated Windows 7, then booted Ubuntu. When I tried to mount the Windows partition, I got this error:
[image]
I'd just read that switching OSes via hibernating was OK as long as you didn't modify files on the other OS's partition, and I'm glad Nautilus ensures you don't, but I need to copy some files from that partition. Is there a way to make Nautilus temporarily mount it as read-only? I was hoping I could just do something like "right-click->Mount as Read-Only" but that's not an option.

**Update**: For the record, I was able to do it from a terminal using `sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -r /dev/sda3 /media/adam/`. It usually mounts to `/media/adam/OS/`, although it wouldn't let me do that since the OS folder didn't exist. Also, I had to authenticate as an admin to unmount it from Nautilus since it was mounted as root (the `mount` command I listed had to be run as root). However, I still a graphical solution would be better and a bit more user-friendly.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is an option in Nautilus to mount a partition/device as read-only.
But, for the record, there is another terminal command to mount the partition as read-only:

```
udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/sda3 --options ro
```

This works at least in Ubuntu 13.04. It mounts to `/media/user/label`, even if the folder doesn't exist, and can be run as user (and unmounted in Nautilus without password prompt). The user must be an administrator (i.e. can use sudo), I think.

`udisksctl` is probably what Nautilus uses to mount devices. The older command that mounted to `/media/label` is `udisks`, if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer GUI, use Disks to indicate how a partition should be mounted. Add the read-only option to always have access to your hibernated W7 partition: http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/10/make-ntfs-partitions-read-only-in-ubuntu/

Comment: Not exactly temporary, but faster than opening a terminal. Thanks!